# Authorization header missing from RestRequest headers map

Tags: apex, authentication, rest, apexrest

I have a publicly exposed web service (Rest Apex) through Sites and I'd like to do basic authentication which I will manage myself. I noticed that when I specify `Authorization: Basic HEREGOESBASE64ENCODEDVALUE` in my HTTP request to my web service, I can't get that key-value pair in the `RestRequest.headers` map. All the other custom headers (if I specify any) are coming across.

Does anyone have explanation of why this specific standard header is not accessible in the RestRequest context?

> I'm dealing with some legacy system and oAuth2.0 authentication is
>   out of the question.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/myMapping/*')
global with sharing class MyClass 
{
    @HttpPost
    global static void doPost()
    {
        RestRequest restRequest = RestContext.request;

        if (restRequest.headers.get('Authorization') == null)
        {
            // always goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try using bearer token instead of basic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce does not allow access to the Authorization header.

If you are using the a Salesforce login with OAuth use UserInfo.getSessionId() to get the Authorization data.

I created a public REST service that uses a shared key for authorization. As a workaround I added a custom header called AuthorizationToken. By checking to ensure this is present and valid I can authorize a call.

Comment: is the list of headers that salesforce blocks documented anywhere? asking about it here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/169797/what-headers-are-returned-in-restrequest-headers-property

Comment: I have not found a documented list yet. I will keep looking and let you know if I find something.

Comment: For anyone still looking, it is documented here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_restrequest.htm?search_text=restrequest