# Retrieve "Authorization" header using apex

Tags: rest-api, apexrest

I have an apex class which has access rights to a salesforce site

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/testsite/*')
global with sharing class MyClass 
{
    @HttpPost
    global static void doPost()
    {
        RestRequest restRequest = RestContext.request;

        System.debug('======== Auth Header: ' + restRequest.headers.get('Authorization'));

    }
}
```

I'm using [hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it/) to send post requests to this site. In the requests I'm setting the authorization header using Basic authentication but for some reason it seem to be always null.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [Authorization header missing from RestRequest headers map](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41004/authorization-header-missing-from-restrequest-headers-map/)

Salesforce does not allow access to the Authorization header.

If you are using the a Salesforce login with OAuth use UserInfo.getSessionId() to get the Authorization data.

I created a public REST service that uses a shared key for authorization. As a workaround I added a custom header called AuthorizationToken. By checking to ensure this is present and valid I can authorize a call.