# What headers are returned in RestRequest.headers property?

Tags: apex, webservices, apexrest, debugging, header

#### Question

Is there an official list of which headers are returned when using the `RestContext.request.headers` property?

#### Background

I know that the returned data is limited, e.g. [it excludes the Authorization header](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41004/authorization-header-missing-from-restrequest-headers-map), but I'm having trouble locating an official list of what gets included and what doesn't. I'm debugging a custom integration and it seems like I'm missing key headers. Hoping there might be a list out there of what salesforce let's me see in the headers and what it doesn't ...